# How to speed up Get func in p5.js?

Tags: p5.js

Is there any way to speed up this piece of code (simplified)? On my Dell m4700 laptop, it works for 1 minute and 10 seconds (the size of the canvas is 1000x1400 pixels).

```
pg = createGraphics(1000,1400);
pg.pixelDensity(1);

***
for(j=0;j<pg.height;j++){
  for(i=0;i<pg.width;i++){
    pg.stroke(cc=pg.get(i,j));
    pg.point(i,j+4);
  }
  }
```

Without this line,

```
pg.stroke(cc=pg.get(i,j));
```

the code executes in milliseconds.

I made another version that works in 20 seconds, but for some reason the result is slightly different visually:

```
  for(j=0;j<pg.height;j++){
  pg.loadPixels();
  for(i=0;i<pg.width;i++){
    let pi = i + (j * pg.width);
    let ri = pi * 4;
    let cr = pg.pixels[ri];
    let cg = pg.pixels[ri + 1];
    let cb = pg.pixels[ri + 2];
    let ca = pg.pixels[ri + 3];
    pg.stroke(color(cr,cg,cb,ca)); 
    pg.point(i,floor(j+4));
  }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point of what you're trying to achieve, but if you simply need to render `pg` why not use something like `image(pg, 0, 0);` (or `image(pg,0,0,theWidth,theHeight);`) ?

Comment: @george-profenza I know it, that's exactly what I do in the next step. I need to implement the effect of shifting each pixel while keeping its color. That's why I use pg.stroke(pg.get(i,j)). My code works great but is slow.

Comment: I see, my bad, I've missed the `i,j+4` part. rendering so many points will be slow. One slight improvement could be to use `pg.vertex()` instead of `pg.point()` (with `pg.beginShape(POINTS);` before the loop and `endShape()` after). It might be faster to allocate a larger `p5.Image` (to ensure you have pixels indices to include the y-shift), which you'd manually clear, then use `pixels[]` instead of `pg.point()`. The fastest will probably be via [p5.Shader](https://itp-xstory.github.io/p5js-shaders/#/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Big edit:

Ok, I miss read the question and was thinking in java's processing not p5js as the OP has properly indicated. So my answer was very wrong. Sorry.

But still the approach exists in p5js and is faster.

p5js store pixels in 1d array, 4 slots for each pixel:

`[pix1R, pix1G, pix1B, pix1A, pix2R, pix2G, pix2B, pix2A...]`
And also the pixel density mathers.

So the code is different, I belive you are looking for something like (no pg here, but the thinking is the same):

```js
 loadPixels();
  let d = pixelDensity();
  let imagesize = 4 * (width * d) * ((height) * d);
  for (let i = 0; i <= imagesize; i += 4) {
    let j = i + 16;//4*4
    pixels[i] = pixels[j];
    pixels[i + 1] = pixels[j + 1];
    pixels[i + 2] = pixels[j + 2];
    pixels[i + 3] = pixels[j + 3];
  }

  updatePixels();
```

Now, to access a given area in the array is a little convoluted, here an example

```js
  //the area data  
  const area_x = 35;
  const area_y = 48;
  const width_of_area = 180;
  const height_of_area = 200;
  
  //the pixel density
  const d = pixelDensity();

  loadPixels();
  // those 2 first loops goes trough every pixel in the area
  for (let x = area_x; x < width_of_area; x++) {
    for (let y = area_y; y < height_of_area; y++) {
      //here we go trough the pixels array to get each value of a pixel
      for (let i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < d; j++) {
          // calculate the index of the 1d array for every pixel
          // 4 values in the array for each pixel
          // y times density times #of pixels plus 
          // x times density times #of pixels
          index = 4 * ((y * d + j) * width * d + (x * d + i));      
          // You can assign raw values for rgb color
          pixels[index] = 255;
          pixels[index + 1] = 30;
          pixels[index + 2] = 200;
          pixels[index + 3] = 255;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
```

Both this examples are at p5js online editor:

1:https://editor.p5js.org/v-k-/sketches/GGVeZvCk7

2: https://editor.p5js.org/v-k-/sketches/kW9lXyK2n

Hope that helps, and sorry for the previus processing answer/code.
cheers

Comment: not quite sure how to change my code?

Comment: I will update the answer so you can see

Comment: Done, ask if still in doubt. :)

Comment: nice (+1): simpler than going for shaders :)

Comment: I understand the idea, but each pixel contains the R, G, B, A values, so the dimension of the loop is not width * height, but 4 * width * height. So I need to change the code like this:

for(let j=0;j<pg.height;j++){
 pg.loadPixels();
    for(let i=0;i<pg.width;i++){
  for(let l=0;l<4;l++){
   pg.pixels[4*((j+4)*pg.width+i)+l] = pg.pixels[4*(j*pg.width+i)+l];
        } 
    }
    pg.updatePixels();
}

But the result is not at all what it should be.

Comment: OPS, sorry I thought you was talking about processing not p5js. My mistake... Yep in p5js the thing work differently. So the above is not quite right. I'll edit again to reflect this, later. Can't do it right  now. But a look here may help you: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/get   and https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pixels Sorry my confusion...

Comment: Meanwhile, have a look here, I fast example using the (j+4) idea. Is this? ;) https://editor.p5js.org/v-k-/sketches/GGVeZvCk7

Comment: Here, now a p5js answer. :)