# How Can I find colors of an image with p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

p5.js beginner here.I'm working on an art project.I want to find all the colors of an image and then use those colors. This is a simple picture with 50-60 colors.

```js
let img;
let f;
function preload() {
  img = loadImage("assets/exp1.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(img.width, img.height);
  pixelDensity(1);
  image(img, 0, 0);

  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  firstCol();

  img.loadPixels();

  for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      let i = (x + y * width) * 4;
      img.pixels[i + 0] = di;
      img.pixels[i + 1] = di1;
      img.pixels[i + 2] = di2;
      img.pixels[i + 3] = di3;

      if (fi !== di && fi1 !== di1 && fi2 !== di2 && fi3 !== di3) {
        print(di, di1, di2, di3);
      }
    }
  }
}

function firstCol() {
  img.loadPixels();
  fi = img.pixels[0];
  fi1 = img.pixels[1];
  fi2 = img.pixels[2];
  fi3 = img.pixels[3];

  //print(fi,fi1,fi3,fi4);
}
```

I tried to make a simple version but It's not even close to what I want to do. Thanks for your help already!

Answer (score 0):

You get that out of the box! :)

p5js store all canvas pixels in 1d array, 4 slots for each pixel:

[pix1R, pix1G, pix1B, pix1A, pix2R, pix2G, pix2B, pix2A...] And also the pixel density mathers.

The same apply to a p5.Image.

```js
let img = loadImage("someURL");

//then

img.loadPixels();

// now img.pixels have what you want.
```

So now:

- `img.pixes[0]` has red value
- `img.pixes[1]` has green value
- `img.pixes[2]` has blue value
- `img.pixes[3]` has alpha value

for the first pixel of the image.

- `img.pixes[4]` has red value
- `img.pixes[5]` has green value
- `img.pixes[6]` has blue value
- `img.pixes[7]` has alpha value

for the second pixel of the image.
and so on...

Working with such a weird array may not be trivial. There is also the method `get(x,y)`, that will return the color of pixel x ,y, you can make your own array then.

But direct access is much faster.

To work any given area (a loaded image for instance) you can adapt this snippet:
(here i'm setting the color of the area, but you can get the idea;)

```js
 //the area data  
  const area_x = 35;
  const area_y = 48;
  const width_of_area = 180;
  const height_of_area = 200;
  //the pixel density
  const d = pixelDensity();

  loadPixels();
  // those 2 first loops goes trough every pixel in the area
  for (let x = area_x; x < width_of_area; x++) {
    for (let y = area_y; y < height_of_area; y++) {
      //here we go trough the pixels array to get each value of a pixel
      for (let i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < d; j++) {
          // calculate the index of the 1d array for every pixel
          // 4 values in the array for each pixel
          // y times density times #of pixels
          // x idem
          index = 4 * ((y * d + j) * width * d + (x * d + i));      
          // numbers for rgb color
          pixels[index] = 255;
          pixels[index + 1] = 30;
          pixels[index + 2] = 200;
          pixels[index + 3] = 255;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

to work with the image remember to use `img.pixels` not just `pixels`

There is this other stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73934484/how-to-speed-up-get-func-in-p5-js/73967556?noredirect=1#comment130624030_73967556) that might be of your interest, and also the two examples there, repeated below, may help you to understand all.

1:https://editor.p5js.org/v-k-/sketches/GGVeZvCk7

2:https://editor.p5js.org/v-k-/sketches/kW9lXyK2n

Comment: After I formatted your code I could see you already knew most of it, sorry. But will leave the answer here as it has some potentially useful info.